# 'Token used too late, {numbers} > {numbers}:

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

With the Google Oauth, I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Token used too late, 1410345101 > 1410341783:

Yesterday the code was working fine, but today it dont want to start anymore and giving me errors. Part of my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I think this is where I have to change my code in order to work.

some more of the code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The token has expired. 
You should get a fresh token using the refresh token or by logging in again.

Thats what the message says "Token used too late, 1410345101 > 1410341783:"

'Now' milliseconds is greater that token expiry milliseconds.

Comment: How would we parse the error and use to send a usable response? As an example, I'd like to return a boolean value depending on whether the token is valid or not.

Answer (score 2):

The access token will expire in 3600 seconds which is indicated in the token response (parameter  `expires_in`).

> {
>     "access_token": "ya29.fQCQfvMjEu9fo6T45*********NfUoxILuk-SPa0puDawVssOss0sP0", 
>     "token_type": "Bearer",
>     **"expires_in": 3600,**
>     "refresh_token": "1/er3tmjZUUmXtr********JoJDDopM_xMww"
>   }

After a successful completion of the OAuth 2 authorization code flow, you will get a refresh token. This refresh token never expires, and you can obtain a new access token by sending a refresh token to the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization server.